# Integral of a function from $-a$ to $a$

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, proof-writing

If $f$ is a continuous function from $[-a,a]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$ and if the definite integral from $-a$ to $a$ of $f$ is equal to 0 (with respect to $x$), then does that mean $f$ must be odd?

I am struggling to find a counter-example so I tried to see if I could prove this statement but got stuck.

Is the statement true?

Comment: Did you mean for a given $a>0$ , for all values of $a$?

Comment: For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos x dx = 0$$
and $\cos$ is even.

Update: OP clarified that this is not for a given $a$, but for all $a>0$, that we have $$\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=0$$
Differentiate the above w.r.t. $a$, and you'll obtain
$f(a)+f(-a)=0$ which means that $f$ is odd.